# Efficient calculation of leading order behavior of rational function under a limit?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, performance-tuning

Considering a rational function, as for example

```
myExpr=(x+3)(2+5x+6x^2)/(x(x-5)(x+20))
```

I would like to have a function that tells me the leading order behavior of `myExpr` under limits to infinity or to zero. Note that I am not interested in explicit coefficients and would like to save computational resources. All I need the function to return is:

```
LeadingOrder[myExpr,{x,0}]
```

> `-1`

and

```
LeadingOrder[myExpr,{x,Infinity}]
```

> `0`

I know there is a built in function that does this for polynomials `Exponent[myPoly,x]` when considering a limit to infinity. So I wonder if this can be done computationally efficiently for rational functions? Thanks for any suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just

```
myExpr = (x + 3) (2 + 5 x + 6 x^2)/(x (x - 5) (x + 20));
Series[myExpr, {x, Infinity, 0}] // Normal
(* 6 *)
Series[myExpr, {x, 0, -1}] // Normal
(* -3/(50 x) *)
```

For this `myExpr`, `Limit[myExpr, x -> Infinity]` works as well.

For ratios of polynomials, as suggested by the OP in a comment, the following may be of use.

```
Exponent[Numerator[myExpr], x] - Exponent[Denominator[myExpr], x]
(* 0 *)
```

indicating that `myExpr` becomes constant for large `x`.  And,

```
-(Exponent[Numerator[myExpr /. x -> 1/y], y] - 
  Exponent[Denominator[myExpr /. x -> 1/y], y])
(* -1 *)
```

indicating that `myExpr` varies as `1/x` for small `x`.

Comment: Yes, I am aware of these functions. Unfortunately, they are too resource hungry for the application I need it for. (Calculating explicit coefficients or limit results is much more than what I am looking for - makes the functions slow.) Thus my question above.

Comment: @Kagaratsch  The solutions I gave are, of course, quite general.  More efficient, special purpose solutions may be possible, but they would need to be tuned to specific classes of expressions.  What sorts of expressions do you have in mind.

Comment: As mentioned in the question, I have rational functions in mind. I don't think I could narrow it down more than that.

Comment: The function in your edit works twice as fast as `Series` and is more universal. Thanks!